# Angular2: How to pass multiple request bodies in http post

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, http-post

I have two arrays

```
@Input() list1: string[];
@Input() list2: string[];
```

which I need to pass to server as an `http post` in `Angular2`. How can I do that?

Currently all I know is this:

```
 this.http.post('/myPostal/postRequestMapping', list1, list2);
```

is it correct?

Comment: i would say make it a part of a single object and ship the payload and then on the server side segregate them AFAIK i donot think that angular has a way to pass two payloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an Object with those arrays.

```
var ob = {};
ob.array1 = []; // Array1.
ob.array2 = []; // Array2.
var data = ob; // Object with arrays

this.http.post('/myPostal/postRequestMapping', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you that :

`this.http.post, JSON.stringify({list1: [], list2: []})`

Comment: what is `myUsername` and `myPassword` ?

Comment: it the keys inside the ob.array (just an exemple it could be anything)